# How to properly anchor popovers in Bootstrap 3x

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

If you look at the bootstrap demo that is hosted [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) And scroll down to the demo that has all 4 buttons. Now click on the left popover, it shows properly. However, When I shrink or extend the screen the popover is no longer anchored to the proper point. Is there a way around this?

Comment: +1 interesting, I've never noticed this. It seems mainly affect horizontal window resizing in my browser (Chrome).

Comment: Looks like there is an open issue on this: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12799

Comment: Thanks Skelly didn't see that!

Comment: Also doesn't stick when scrolling

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the container property for the popover.

http://jsfiddle.net/yvkhbw4b/1/

See the attached example. Show both popovers then resize the window from xs breakpoint to sm breakpoint. You will see the top item will seperate from the button as the container defaults to body. (I'm also setting it to body though options). The second item is attached to the parent div so that one remains attached to the element even though the breakpoint changed.

[Documentation on popover options](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-options)

> Appends the popover to a specific element. Example: container: 'body'.
>   This option is particularly useful in that it allows you to position
>   the popover in the flow of the document near the triggering element -
>   which will prevent the popover from floating away from the triggering
>   element during a window resize.

```
$('#btn1').popover({
        'container': 'body'
});

$('#btn2').popover({
        'container': '.col-sm-12'
});
```

**Potential Fix:** you could add the following code. Currently only handles bottom aligned popovers but you can add options for other alignments.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('.popover.in').each(function () {
        var el = $('[aria-describedby="' + this.id + '"]');
        if ($(this).hasClass('bottom')){
        $(this).css('top',el.offset().top + el.outerHeight(true));
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yvkhbw4b/2/